# rolling a sum of 6 or less, on 3 dice

Tags: probability-or-statistics

What is the probability of rolling a sum of 6 or less when rolling 3 dice(six sided) at once.

I understand how to get the probability of rolling the sum of 6 but of 6 or less confuses me.

Comment: I recommend that this question be moved b the author to [math.se], because it has little to do with Mathematica software.

Comment: No *Mathematica* in the question, so…

Comment: `Probability[d1+d2+d3<=6,Thread[{d1,d2,d3}\[Distributed]DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1,6}]]]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find all the possible combinations which satisfy the constrains

```
allpos = Tuples[{Range[6], Range[6], Range[6]}];
select = Cases[allpos, a_ /; Total[a] <= 6];
```

and you can easily get the probability

```
prob = Length[select]/Length[allpos]
```

the output is

> 5/54